# CSS border on div suddenly stopped working in chrome. Still works in firefox

Tags: jquery, css, border

So as the title already says, something weird happened just now. I was working on my memory game, after re-opening the page the border around the divs when navigating with keyboard arrows stopped showing up. (click in the window to get arrows to work.) I always use google chrome but now that this happened I went over to firefox and the border shows up there :s

Is it same for you?: http://jsfiddle.net/94jerdaw/USesV/

I doubt it's the css because I haven't changed it, atleast not **intentionally...**

As I mentioned, click the result frame to get focus, and then see if you get this correctly in chrome/FF:

```
$('#' + tar).addClass("target");
```

connected to this:

```
.target{
    width:94px;
    height:94px;
    border:3px solid black;
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you're using the default box sizing. The ":after" content is obscuring the surrounding box. I don't know why it's different between Chrome and Firefox but one of them is surely wrong :-)

Comment: If you add a CSS rule like `* {box-sizing: border-box;}` that helps, though it makes the ":hover" rule kinda weird.

Comment: hey there, did you already checked my answer on your last question about your game? it seems that your memory is following me. I will update a complete version tomorrow. To stay on topic i am not able to get the arrow keys working on chrome, setup: os x 10.8.3, Chrome Version 25.0.1364.172

Comment: I had it working, and I did my completely own solution to the movement.

Comment: Flag if you want, but thanks for giving me the nice playing experience after busy day. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a quick fix for you.  Add content:""; to the target css and it works.

```
.target{
    content:"";

    width:94px;
    height:94px;
    border:3px solid black;
}
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/CZdux

Comment: Glad to help.  I hadn't seen jsfiddle before, so that's definitely going into a bookmark folder :)

Answer (score 2):

I see the problem as well in Chrome.  A workaround is to add a second class to your cards (for instance, `.card-grey`) and apply the `:after` pseudo-element to that class.  Then, when you add `.target`, you can also remove `.card-grey` and vice versa.

http://jsfiddle.net/USesV/1/

Comment: The color isn't supposed to be shown when using the arrows. The class is there to act like a pretend hover. What I don't understand is how it was working flawlessly just a minute before, and now the borders don't show..  I haven't done ANY change since then, and I even tried restoring dropbox content without getting my good results back :s

Comment: Well, Chrome pushes updates pretty often.  Have you restarted your browser recently?

Comment: Sure did, gonna try n see for update logs of chrome. Possibly revert to an older version :)